# Make top level terms un-selectable in hierarchical taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy like this:

```
Color
-blue
-green

Size
-large
-small
```

I need to use 1 vocabulary not 2. However I need 'Color' and 'Size' to not be selectable. If I create a hierarchal taxonomy is there a way to make certain (the top level) terms un-selectable by nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using  [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select/) module you can do that and configure it to ***Force the user to choose a term from deepest level***, see the below screenshot.

[image]

and also take a look at this [Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget](https://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) module, I think it have the option to select only child term and I'm not sure about this module.

Comment: I tried out Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget, but couldn't find any option to limit/force deepest level. [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module (using that instead of Hierarchical Select since there's a D8 version) so far seems to do this fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Taxonomy container](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_container) module, it does exactly what you want. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... provides an extra widget called «Select list (with groups)» to term reference fields.
>
> Drupal 6 version of the module just alters taxonomy form and converts to optgroups all top-level options in the select list.
>
> Note: [Chosen module](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) can help you make select boxes much more user-friendly.